# Is this a good way to define "n-paths" in a type?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\succ}{succ}$

Define these two type families by "indexed induction induction."
$$\text{_-boundary} : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}$$
$$\text{_-path} : \prod_{n : \mathbb{N}} \prod_{A : \mathcal{U}}  \text{$n$-boundary}(A) \to \mathcal{U}$$
The intention is that $\text{$n$-boundary}(A)$ is the boundary of an $n$-dimensional path in $A$, so for example when $n = 1$, I expect $\text{1-boundary}(A) \simeq A \times A$, since the boundary of a path is two points. Similarly $\text{$n$-path}(A,bd)$ I think is the type of $n$-dimensional paths in $A$ with boundary $bd$.

$\text{_-boundary}(A)$ is freely generated by:

- $\text{bd}_0: \text{0-boundary}(A)$.
- $\text{bd}_{\text{_}}$ :$\prod_{n : \mathbb{N}} \prod_{bd : \text{$n$-boundary}(A)} \text{$n$-path}(A, bd) \to \text{$n$-path}(A, bd) \to \succ(n)\text{-boundary}(A, bd)$

The constructor says $\text{bd}_0$ says that $0$-dimensional paths, i.e. points have trivial boundaries.The constructor $bd_n$ says that any two $n$-dimensional paths which share a boundary form an $n+1$-dimensional boundary.

$\text{_-path}(A)$ is generated by:

- $p_0 : \prod_{a : A} \text{0-path}(A, \text{bd}_0)$
- $p_\text{_}: \prod_{n : \mathbb{N}}\prod_{bd : \text{$n$-boundary}(A)} \prod_{p, q : n\text{-path}(bd)} p = q \to \succ(n)\text{-path}(A, \text{bd}_{\text{succ}(n)}(p,q))$

The constructor $p_0$ says that points in $A$ form $0$-dimensional paths in $A$. The constructor $p_n$ says that given any two $n$-dimensional paths which share a boundary, if there is a higher path between them, then there is an $n+1$-dimensional path between them with an appropriate boundary.

Of course, I feel stupid for not coming up with the much more elegant definition from Kuen-Bang Hou, which you can see here: https://github.com/favonia/homotopy/blob/master/Path/HigherOrder.agda. But I'm still curious about this definition. Is there a way of combining indexed type families and induction-induction that can make the above work correctly?